# get-storedCredential not able to fetch windows credential

Tags: powershell, credential-manager

When I run the command get-StoredCredential for a generic credential it is giving me the output which makes me agree that the credentials are getting fetched in object form.

However, when I use same command to fetch windows credential, it is giving me blank output.
Is there any way to fetch windows credential? Also, can NAS shared path be configured and used under Generic credentials?